# usb drive persistent mapping(ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: linux, rsync, path, usb-flash-drive, mapping

I'd like to map an usb drive to a path under ubuntu 16.04. The idea is to use rsync to backup some folders to this usb drive whenever I plug it. Is there any way for the system to recognize the usb drive from its manufacturer id for instance and then map it to a unchanging path?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a package called `usbmount` which looks awesome!
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/134797/how-to-automatically-mount-an-usb-device-on-plugin-time-on-an-already-running-sy?rq=1

Alternately, you can employ SystemD to help: [Automount USB drives with systemd](https://serverfault.com/questions/766506/automount-usb-drives-with-systemd?rq=1)

Initially I would have suggested to use UUID & autofs, there have been a few answers already that might help. Udev rules would work for "when you plug it in", however, that answer is better.

**https://superuser.com/a/817797**

https://serverfault.com/a/530295/35383

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingUUID